# Condition on $c$ for a contraction map

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, vector-spaces

I am extending Example 2.2 on [this sheet](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece580/n2.pdf).

Suppose $f(x(s),s)$ is such that $$|f(x(s),s)-f(y(s),s)|\leq K |x-y|\quad\text{for some }K>0.\tag{1}$$

and $x,y\in C[0,t_f]:\,\,\,t_f<\infty$

Also, let $T$ be such that $$[T(x)](s)=\int f(x(s),s)ds + x_0.\tag{2}$$

But this time let $$\|x\|_c=\sup\limits_{s\in [0,t_f]}|x(s)\exp(-cx)|\quad\text{for some }c\in \mathbb{R}.\tag{3}$$

I want to find the strictest condition possible on $c$ such that $T$ is a contraction.

I know that it is a function of $RK$... and that we should plug (1) into (2) then in turn into (3). But I don't know how to deal with the $\exp$ to get the (strictest) conditions.

Added: in other words, for what values of $c$ would I get $T$ to be a contraction map?

Thanks.